# wordpress remove meta name author tag

Tags: php, wordpress

On my wordpress site I have a author meta tag:

```
<meta name="author" content="Author Name">
```

I have deleted this meta tag with this code in my template folder. File name is header.php. Here is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
wp_head(); /** we hook up in wp_booster @see td_wp_booster_functions::hook_wp_head */
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_replace('/<meta name="author" content="(.*?)">/mis', '', $output);
echo $output;
?>
```

It works great, but I think it is not a good solution. Is there some another way?

Comment: Why don't you remove the meta tag where you have the loop? Why do you do such a horrible thing? :D

Comment: The tag printed by wp_head(); function. And I don't know where is wp_head(); function's file.

Comment: Do you want to remove just the author meta? Are you using some plugins (Yoast, etc)?

Comment: Yes I want to remove only author meta. No I am not using plugins.

Comment: What theme are you using? Maybe the theme is adding the author tag. Check you functions file.

Comment: I am using newsmag

Comment: add this code in your function.php add_filter( 'wpseo_meta_author', '__return_false' );